# How to generate pdf with vertical table?

Tags: jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to generate a pdf report containing data in a vertical table. Is there any library to achieve this functionality? I can use the following format of the dictionary to render data

```
context = {
"name":["A","B","C","D","E"]
"age":[23,23,23,23,23],
}
```

but data is huge so it can affect performance.is there any other way to achieve this?I just want to generate pdf report with the table in the following format :

```
| Name     | A              |       23      |
| Age      | B              |       23      |
```

Comment: I would try WeasyPrint or puppeteer for this.

Comment: Try the package xhtml2pdf & BytesIO. You need to add ```from xhtml2pdf import pisa```